# State setting, state rehydration and api calls are happening twice

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, apisauce

I'm using

```json
apisauce: ^2.1.6,
react: 18.1.0,
react-native: 0.70.4,
react-redux: ^8.0.4,
redux: ^4.2.0,
redux-logger: ^3.0.6,
redux-persist: ^6.0.0,
redux-saga: ^1.2.1
```

The problem I'm facing is each and every time I open and close the app or set state or hit an API it's happening twice. Can someone help me out with this?

[image: Screenshot of google debugger]

I'm expecting the setState, rehydration and api calls should hit only once

## Store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import devToolsEnhancer from 'remote-redux-devtools';
import creatSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import rootSaga from '../sagas/rootSaga';
import loaderReducer from '../reducers/loaderReducer';

const sagaMiddleware = creatSagaMiddleware();
const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, logger];

const config = {
    key: 'root',
    debug: true,
    whitelist: [],
    storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const reducers = persistReducer(config, combineReducers({
    loader: loaderReducer
}));

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: reducers,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({ immutableCheck: false, serializableCheck: false }).concat(middlewares),
    enhancers: [applyMiddleware(...middlewares), devToolsEnhancer({ realtime: true })]
});
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

## reducer.js

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  message: ''
};

export const loaderReducer = createSlice({
  name: 'loader',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setLoader: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = action && action.payload ? action.payload.isLoading || false : false;
      state.message = action && action.payload ? action.payload.message || '' : '';
    }
  }
});

export const { setLoader } = loaderReducer.actions;

export default loaderReducer.reducer;
```

## rootSaga.js

```js
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import {
    watchGenerateImageThumbnail
} from './userServiceSagas';

function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        watchGenerateImageThumbnail()
    ]);
};

export default rootSaga;
```

## userServiceSagas.js

```js
import { call, put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import types from '../reducers/types/types';
import * as userServiceApis from '../services/user-service';
import { setLoader } from '../reducers/loaderReducer';
export function* generateImageThumbnail(action) {
    try {
        if (action && action.params && action.params.background != true)
            yield put(setLoader({ isLoading: true, message: 'Getting Payment Intent...' }));

        const generateImageThumbnailResponse = yield call(userServiceApis.generateImageThumbnail, action.params);
        if (action && action.params && action.params.background != true)
            yield put(setLoader(null));

        if (generateImageThumbnailResponse.status != 200)
            return action.onError(generateImageThumbnailResponse.originalError.message || generateImageThumbnailResponse.data);

        return action.onSuccess(generateImageThumbnailResponse.data);
    } catch (error) {
        if (action && action.params && action.params.background != true)
            yield put(setLoader(null));
        action.onError(error);
    }
}

export function* watchGenerateImageThumbnail() {
    yield takeEvery(types.GENERATE_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL, generateImageThumbnail);
}
```

Comment: does this answer your question? https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24502 seem react 18 feature.

Comment: for me, useEffect is called only once

Comment: "Can someone help me out with this?" possibly, but we'd likely need to see a minimal reproduction case with actual code.

Answer (score 2):

I think its beacuse you are running your ReactApp in StrictMode, go to index.js(main js file) and remove StrictMode.

Comment: ```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```
This is what I have in index.js file

Comment: You should provide to us more information :)

Comment: have added what you asked. can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

They are just extra Logs because of StrictMode in React. Nonetheless , the store won't be effected by this.
Just Remove "React.StrictMode" Tag In Index.js file or main.jsx depending on your environment.